# Preselect an Item in a MVC DropDownList

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Please suggest what is wrong in this code. I am unable to select an item

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Users";
    objUser user = (objUser)Session["userdet"];
}

@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.User, new SelectList(Model.UserList, "Id", "Name", user.Id))
```

Also should I use DropDownListFor or DropDownLisT?

Comment: You are trying to bind an ID to an object, try this instead: `@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.User.Id, new SelectList(Model.UserList, "Id", "Name"))`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the code "model => model.User".

What is ".User" set to? If it is not == user.Id, then the code won't work. I think model.User is overriding "user.Id" on the end of the statement so "user.UserId" does not make sense

Answer (score 0):

John Stuntz is correct, the xxxFor helpers don' take the Selected property in the SelectListItem (contained in the SelectList object) into account. What you can do in your controller is:

```
model.User = user.id;
return View();
```

and in your view:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.User, new SelectList(Model.UserList, "Id", "Name"))
```